# Puppet 6 how to split or truncate domian name

Tags: puppet

I have array of domains like this:
`'us1.domain.com', 'us2.domain.com', 'us3.domain.com', 'anotherdomain.com', 'yet.third.com'`

I would split or truncate these domain names to:

```
domain.com
anotherdomain.com
third.com
```

Could anybody prompt me, please?

This new array will use for certificate file name.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve that problem like this:

```puppet
$array = [
  'us1.domain.com', 'us2.domain.com', 'us3.domain.com',
  'anotherdomain.com', 'yet.third.com'
]
notice($array.map |$x| { $y=$x.split(/\./); [$y[-2], $y[-1]].join('.') }.unique)
```

Testing:

```
▶ puppet apply test.pp 
Notice: Scope(Class[main]): [domain.com, anotherdomain.com, third.com]
Notice: Compiled catalog for 192-168-1-103.tpgi.com.au in environment production in 0.05 seconds
Notice: Applied catalog in 0.01 seconds
```

Key insights there:

- You can split each element on a period using using the split function.
- You can take the last and second last elements of an array using $arr[-1] and $arr[-2].
- You can join it all back together again using the join function.
- You can transform the list into a new list using the map function.
- You can remove the duplicates using the unique function.